# Rubaxa sortable, dropping on empty space to the right of inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, rubaxa-sortable

I'm trying to use the Rubaxa sortable library with inline-block elements.

An example is on the following jsbin page:

http://jsbin.com/qidalolero/1/edit

I've noticed the following behaviours:

- The first item picked up (in the order picked up, nothing to do with element order) can be dragged into the red box anywhere, and it will sit nicely on the left (desired behaviour).
- The second and third, however, must be either

  - dragged over an existing item, or
  - dragged into the empty space below the list

How can I make it so that items can be dropped to the right of existing items, at the same height? My application doesn't have the empty space underneath so users have to drag over an existing item before the ghost item appears in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in [this issue](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/356).